# Hide Toast on Android

Tags: android, toast

I am developing an application that uses system activity to add a contact to phone's memory. This external activity launches a Toast after saving the contact. Is there any possibility to get rid of it? It would be perfect if I could get a reference to it to call cancel() or cancel all queued Toasts. Is there any Toast manager?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. You could cancel the Toast if you had a reference to it but since it is created by a separate activity you can't access it.

Answer (score 16):

If you create a Toast message as explained in the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
```

Now you can cancel the toast with `toast.cancel` see the documentation of the [Toast class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29)